# Cannot locate xaml page in my WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

[image][image]hi i have 3 folders in project namely Model,View, View Model. I moved my Xaml to View folder. My solution gets build properly buy when i run it shows the Error "cannot locate the source Userregistration.xaml".

Heres is my complete code

i have added themy folder structure for the reference. please help me i m not able to figure out this issue.

View

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMDemo.UserRegistrationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
    Title="Registration Window" Height="300" Width="575.851">
    <Window.Resources>

        <viewmodel:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <viewmodel:DatetimeToDateConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Student.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="76,0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Age" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Student.Age, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FillCourseId}"  Name="cmb_CourseIDName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164.191,5,0,0" 
                  Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168.342" Grid.RowSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"  FontSize="8" IsReadOnly="True" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Student.SCourseIDName,Mode=TwoWay}" RenderTransformOrigin="1.431,0.77">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseID, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ComboBox>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="62.551,0,78.762,76.829"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="85.152" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView  >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Joining Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JoiningDate, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Course Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SCourseIDName.CourseName}" Width="80"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="CourseId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SCourseIDName.CourseID}" Width="60"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string CourseID { get; set; }

        public Student SCourseIDName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        static String connectionString = @"Data Source=RITESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SIT_Ritesh_DB;Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        private Student _student;
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
        private ICommand _SubmitCommand;

        public Student Student
        {
            get
            {
                return _student;
            }
            set
            {
                _student = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Student");
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _fillCourseId = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        public ObservableCollection<Student> FillCourseId
        {
            get { return _fillCourseId; }
            set
            {
                _fillCourseId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SystemStatusData");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get
            {
                return _students;
            }
            set
            {
                _students = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
            }
        }

        private Student _selectedcourseIdname;

        public Student SelectedCourseIdName
        {
            get { return _selectedcourseIdname; }
            set
            {
                _selectedcourseIdname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCourseIdName");

            }

        }
        public string SelectedCourseId
        {
            get { return _selectedcourseIdname.CourseID; }
            set
            {
                _selectedcourseIdname.CourseID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCourseId");

            }

        }


        public string SelectedCourseName
        {
            get { return _selectedcourseIdname.CourseName; }
            set
            {
                _selectedcourseIdname.CourseName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCourseName");

            }

        }

        public ICommand SubmitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SubmitCommand == null)
                {
                    _SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Submit(),
                        null);
                }
                return _SubmitCommand;
            }
        }

        //********************************************* Functions*******************************************// 

        public void GetCourseIdFromDB()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dev_Course", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                // Student Student = new Student();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    FillCourseId.Add(new Student
                    {
                        CourseID = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                        CourseName = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString()
                    });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Student = new Student();
            Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            Students.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Students_CollectionChanged);
            GetCourseIdFromDB();
        }

        void Students_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
        }

        private void Submit()
        {
            Student.JoiningDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
            //Students.Add(SelectedCourseIdName);
            Students.Add(Student);
            Student = new Student();
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

DateTimeConverter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class DatetimeToDateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
            return date.ToString("MM/d/yyyy");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class ViewModelBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to update the xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo" to xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo. ViewModel"

Answer (score 2):

you need to change it in the app.xmal in the line of the StartupUri
that he will be contact to the xmal in the View

example:

in the app.xmal file

```
<Application x:Class="UserRegistration.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserRegistration"
         StartupUri="View/UserRegistrationView.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit app.xaml to point to the correct view file (including the folder name in the path) which in your case is the UserRegistrationView.Xaml. The app.xaml is responsible for starting your app not to view xaml code.

The folder name may not be required. I use Resharper which creates a namespace for each folder within a project in visual studio.